# If a quotient of a metric space is an LCH space then it is normal

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $\pi:X\to Y$ be an open, continuous, surjective map (quotient map) onto locally compact Hausdorff space $Y$ (in particular, $Y$ is completely regular). Does it follow that $Y$ is a normal space?

I don't know which assumptions are needed and if it is true.
(It can be assumed moreover: $X$ has finite covering dimension, i.e. Lebesgue dimension. It can be also helpful for me to show that $Y$ has finite covering dimension in this setting).

EDIT: If $X$ is separable then it is secong countable and since the quotient map is open, $Y$ is second countable as well. Now, $Y$ is a second countable, regular Hausdorff space and by Urysohn's metrization theorem it is metrizable. In this case, we are done.

Thank you for your time and for any help!

Comment: Is your map $\pi$ also closed by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly easy zero-dimensional counterexample. I have no proof that
it is strongly zero-dimensional, but that seems quite likely.

The counterexample I am referring to is the [rational sequence topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_sequence_topology)
.
It is shown in many places that this is a zero-dimensional locally compact
Hausdorff space, but not normal.

In addition, since basic open sets are either singletons or homeomorphic
to the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, it is locally metrizable.
The latter property implies that it is an image of a metrizable 
space by a open continuous mapping. Indeed, if $C$ is a cover by metrizable
open subspaces, then $X = \coprod_{U\in C} U$ is metrizable and the 
combination of inclusion mappings $U\hookrightarrow Y$ is a local 
homeomorphism.